# Xamarin Studio resource not found

Tags: xml, google-maps, resources, android-resources, xamarin-studio

I am trying to get the MapsAndLocationDemo_v3 SimpleMapDemo working in Xamarin Studio. I am getting this error when building:

```
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Android\Monodroid samples\monodroid-samples-master\MapsAndLocationDemo_v3\Components\googleplayservices-13.0\lib\android\13\content\google-play-services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml(0,0): Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark'). (SimpleMapDemo)
```

Can I have a description of what this error means, and how to fix it as well (if possible)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the **drawable folder** in the **resource folder** (res), you have a file called:

```
common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
```

This file references an image with the file name:

```
common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark" (png, probably)
```

Add an image file with that name to the **drawable folder** and make sure it is set to be an **AndroidResource**.